# "Result in" or "result to"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

I am trying to help a friend to write his CV. I don't know which preposition to use in the following paragraph:

> Advance Marketing Staff Knowledge & Skills Which Lead To Dramatically Increase In The Branch Customers. And Also **Result In** Several Competitive Branches In The Same City To Close.

Should *result in* or *result to* be used? I feel like it should be *result in* but I am not sure.

Any suggestions or improvements are also welcome.

Comment: I think this question steers dangerously close to *please improve my English*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: come on, it is just an innocent question. anyway can you improve my English . . . .? _Just kidding_ ;)

Comment: Well I haven't voted to close the question, but it's difficult to ignore the rest of your sentence apart from *result in*. Inviting replies to the unasked **"are there any mistakes in this text?"** which the FAQ debars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Result in* is idiomatic and quite acceptable, but rewrite the rest of the sentence:

> Advanced Marketing Staff knowledge and skills which led to a dramatic increase in branch customers, and also resulted in the closure of several competitive branches in the same city.

I think past tense is appropriate and it isn't necessary to capitalize every word.

*Result to* is strange and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

*Result in* means "have a specified end or outcome," which is what you are saying.