# Result in or result into?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

My instinct tells me to use *result in*. But in my working environment, it systems, somebody came up with *result into*. Example:

> To use this programs in parallel can ***result into*** a crash...

I have read [To gain insight into or on?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15667/to-gain-insight-into-or-on) and ["Result in" or "result to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35305/result-in-or-result-to) . And when I enter result in `dict.cc` I get only results for *result in*.

So, is there any correct usage of *result into* and if so, what is the difference?

Comment: You might want to consider [this NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+resulted+into%2Cwhich+resulted+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhich%20resulted%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhich%20resulted%20in%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "... this programs..." is problematic.

Comment: ‘‘To use these programs in parallel can …’’, while not wrong, seems awkward; I would say ‘‘Using these programs in parallel can …’’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the promixal demonstrative *this* when the plural *these programs* is required does not inspire confidence. The alternative *result into* instead of *result in* is, however, a regular feature of South Asian English:

> 3 Apr 2018 · Uniindia: New Delhi, Apr 3 (UNI) Finance Minister Arun Jaitley has said that the impact of demonetisation and GST implementation has [*resulted into*](http://www.uniindia.com/%7E/impact-of-demonetisation-gst-resulted-into-higher-formalisation-of-economy-jaitley/Business%20Economy/news/1188412.html) higher formalisation of economy.
>
> The difficult terrain and topography of this area coupled with lack of communication facilities with the plains [*resulted into*](https://books.google.de/books?id=7obxhDgyDf4C&pg=PA51&dq=%22resulted+into%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlvf_f0J7bAhWRmbQKHUohBY8Q6AEIOTAE) the isolation of the tribes of these areas and as such they have a distinct social structure of their own. — J. P. Singh Rana, *Himalayan Heritage*, 1997,51.
>
> Incidents such as marriage, death of a family member [*have often resulted into*](https://books.google.de/books?id=skKAAAAAMAAJ&q=%22resulted+into%22&dq=%22resulted+into%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQsar10Z7bAhVGPFAKHZcACFA4ChDoAQhDMAY) mobility for some member of the household. — Ram B. Chhetri, Om Prasad Gurung,  *Anthropology and Sociology of Nepal*,1999.
>
> This [*resulted into*](https://books.google.de/books?id=nKqF_AgDd4gC&pg=PA29&dq=%22resulted+into%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVmoea057bAhVGmbQKHR_oBVo4FBDoAQgsMAI) the formation of three original British Indian provinces. — Braja Bihārī Kumāra, *Small States Syndrome in India*, 1998, 29.

In any other variety of English, this would be considered a highly non-idiomatic error. The reasoning is simple: a result comes at the end of a process; it is not a process itself. Thus the verb cannot collocate with the preposition *into*, which implies directed motion (*I drove into town*) or a change of one state into another (*leather made into shoes, a prince turned into a frog, went into cardiac arrest*). It‘s not like there’s a bunch of resulting going on until you get to the end result.

Speakers of Indian English apparently see the verb *result* as a transformative process, thus having direction and duration, while Americans and Britons see it as an arrival at a single point.